# How to split multiple big text files into multiple files using powershell

Tags: file, powershell, split, delimiter

I have a folder with 1 or more files like this:

```
bigfileA.txt
bigfileB.txt
bigfileC.txt
```

Each file contains 1 line and is delimited by `'`
For example, `bigfileA.txt` may contain `abcdef'ghijklmnop'qrst`

How can I use powershell so that when I run the .ps file it will automatically split all files in the specified directory into multiple files?
The output will look like this:

```
bigfileA1.txt --> abcdef
bigfileA2.txt --> ghijklmnop
bigfileA3.txt --> qrst
bigfileB1.txt --> uvw
bigfileB2.txt --> xyz
bigfileC1.txt --> ... and so on...
... and so on...
```

Can someone help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script will go through a directory you choose and create a text file with the name of the base file + the current index (For example `bigfileA` + `1`) and will have the delimited value inside.

```
$bigfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\bigfiles\here'

ForEach ($path in $bigfiles)
{
    $contents = Get-Content $path.FullName

    ForEach ($line in $contents)
    {
        $splitItems = $line.split("'")

        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $splitItems.count; $i++)
        {
            New-Item -Path "$($path.Directory)\$($path.BaseName)$i.txt" -ItemType File -Value $splitItems[$i]
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Re-read question, must have misinterpreted the first time. Updated code.

If you want the files to start at 1 instead of 0 change this line

```
New-Item -Path "$($path.Directory)\$($path.BaseName)$i.txt" -ItemType File -Value $splitItems[$i]
```

to this

```
New-Item -Path "$($path.Directory)\$($path.BaseName)$($i+1).txt" -ItemType File -Value $splitItems[$i]
```

We're simply changing the `$i` to `$($i+1)`

**Functional Edit**

*Has not been tested and was put together quickly because i'm at work but it's at least a start :)*

```
function Split-BigFiles
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='All', 
                  SupportsShouldProcess=$false, 
                  PositionalBinding=$false)]
    Param
    (
        # Paths to bigfiles
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false, 
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
                   Position=0,
                   ParameterSetName='All')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String[]]
        $Path
    )

    Begin
    {
        Write-Verbose "Starting Function Split-BigFiles"
    }
    Process
    {
        ForEach($folder in $Path)
        {
            Try
            {
                $bigfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -ErrorAction Stop
            }
            Catch
            {
                Write-Warning "Oh no i couldn't get the folder! This is the error i got $($_.Exception.Message)"
            }

            if ($bigfiles)
            {
                ForEach ($path in $bigfiles)
                {
                    $contents = Get-Content $path.FullName

                    ForEach ($line in $contents)
                    {
                        $splitItems = $line.split("'")

                        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $splitItems.count; $i++)
                        {
                            New-Item -Path "$($path.Directory)\$($path.BaseName)$i.txt" -ItemType File -Value $splitItems[$i]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "Exiting Function Split-BigFiles"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. Just 1 more question, how can I convert this to a .ps1? (absolute powershell beginner here :))

Comment: Two ways, copy the above text into notepad and save as a `.ps1` or open up `Powershell ISE`, paste the code and File -> Save.

Comment: Hi Bluecakes, sorry I wasn't clear... How can I parameterize the path? I tried the templates online on how to create a function but failed.

Comment: Added an edit to include a sample function, has not been tested but should provide the basics to making this into a function with parameters.  Can be called using `Split-BigFiles -Path C:\bigfilesfolder1,C:\bigfilesfolder2`

Comment: Thanks! I placed the code in Split-Bigfiles.ps1. And then ran .\Split-Bigfiles -path D:\Temp. But for some reason, nothing happens when I run it. It does not even output the Begin{} write-verbose. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because it's a function in a script file you need to first run `.\Split-BigFiles.ps1` to load the script and then you need to use the function like so `Split-BigFiles -Path D:\Temp`